# GCP secret manager returns connections string itself, how can I have it return my secret?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I have a secret on GCP, namely greeting with the secret-value being "Hello". When in my application I have the following code.

```
@Value("${sm://projects/221608087928/secrets/greeting}")
private String databasePassword;

@RequestMapping(value ="/test-user")
public String getUser()
      return this.databasePassword;
}
```

I have the value (projects/221608087928/secrets/greeting) by running the following command.

```
gcloud secrets describe "$secret_name"| grep name
```

I would assume my browser returning "Hello". However it returns "//projects/221608087928/secrets/greeting". I have the gcp-secret-manager dependency installed in my POM. How can I have the following code return the secret-value?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by updating dependency from

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

to

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```